# Deploying node js app and next js app which both sits in same project

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, next.js

I have a `NextJS 13` project.

Within that same project I have a `Node` project that sits inside a folder called `server`.

When I deploy it to production, this is how my `Dockerfile` looks.

```
FROM path-to-node16-runtime:latest

COPY node_modules ./node_modules
COPY index.js ./dist/index.js
COPY .next ./dist/.next

ARG PORT=8080
ENV PORT ${PORT}
EXPOSE ${PORT}
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The deployment works but my UI is just static.

 Missing content from the nodejs project inside the server folder.

Cos in nextjs I perform api calls like following to fetch data:

```
export const apiDomain = 'http://localhost:5000';
const res = await fetch(`${apiDomain}/api/global`);
```

This apiDomain and rest service is coming from that node project inside server folder which works when I develop locally.

At present when I deploy, I do build both the next js app and node js app via npm run build.

My build scripts in package.json at top level under the nextjs project as follows:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build:next": "next build",
    "build": "npm run build-backend && npm run build-frontend",
    "start:server": "cd server && npm start",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run start:server\" \"next start\"",
    "build-frontend": "npm install && npm run build:next",
    "build-backend": "cd server && npm install"
  },
```

Do I need to modify my Dockerfile to bring in the nodejs project too so that they start working together with the nextjs app?

P.S: Not too familiar with docker and the concept of deploying where both nextjs and nodejs are essentially inside the same folder and being deployed together.

Looking for some guidance here. Pls advice. Thanks.

UPDATE:

Full folder structure.

```
Project
  .github
  .next
  node_modules
  server (node project)
   node_modules
   index.js
   package.json
  src (nextjs project)
   app
   components
  Dockerfile
  index.js (This is the entry point. See file content below)
  package.json
```

Entry point index file

```
const http = require('http');
const { parse } = require('url');
const next = require('next');

const app = next({ dev: false, dir: __dirname });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
const options = {};

options.agent = new http.Agent(options);
process.env.PORT = '8080';

const middleware = (req, res) => {
  const url = parse(req.url, true);
  handle(req, res, url);
};

(async () => {
  await app.prepare();
  http.createServer(options, middleware).listen(process.env.PORT);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You CANNOT use `localhost:5000`. Because it's not running (or *EXPOSE*d) on port `5000` on `localhost` in the container. Even if you had `EXPOSE 5000`, it wouldn't work - as the host needs to configure to forward requests directed to port `5000` in the container.
2. It depends. Although I don't know NextJS, but as far as my general knowledge about full-stack frameworks go, NextJS apps should be able to run by itself due to it being shipped with some server-side functionalities. For example, NextJS uses file-system based routing, which the included server should be able to pick up and send responses accordingly.

Now my two cents:

1. You're `COPY`ing `node_modules` folder from the host to the container, which is highly discouraged. It's the best to let the container download the dependencies on its own, using the container's operating system. I'd change `COPY node_modules ./node_modules` with `RUN npm i --prod`.
2. It looks like your NextJS app is running on port `8080` and it's also `EXPOSE`d in *Dockerfile*. Assuming the NextJS app is served using the built-in server, you can just use `/api/global` directly while making the HTTP calls. Even if your app is served by your own custom Node.js server, the client is still part of that server, so that should still work.

---

P.S: One optional edit in the *Dockerfile*:

```
ARG PORT=8080
ENV PORT ${PORT}
```

is redundant. You can just write

```
ENV PORT 8080
```

and the following lines will still work like that.

Comment: Thanks but what about my node project that is sitting inside the server folder though. Do I need to mention it inside the Dockerfile. It has its own node_modules and index.js file.

Comment: If you can share the full folder structure of your project, I'll be able to help you better.

Comment: Added details in the question above.

Comment: What's the difference between `./index.js` and `./server/index.js`?